# How can I switch to an external db with Views API?

Tags: 7, views, database

In Drupal 7 I have a module with a `hook_form()`. This form is saving data into an external postgresql database.

I want to create a views to display data recorded. So I `used hook_views_data()` to create a mapping between the view and my custom tables. I created a view with admin but in this view I have the following error :

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'cars' doesn't exist
```

I have tried something like this but it doesn't run :

```
function carshop_views_pre_render(&$view) {
  if ($view->name == 'cars_overview') {
    db_set_active('carsdb');
  }
db_set_active();
}
```

Comment: This is not duplicate question. This case is particular with Views and the solution provided by @Aram...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds as if you need the [Views Database Connector](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_database_connector) module.

From the project page:

> Views Database Connector is a powerful module that gives Views full access to external database tables found in the settings for your Drupal installation. With this module, you can setup a view around any table in any database configuration. This can be extremely useful to pull external data from a database to show to your users in a view.